# Getting reference to dynamically created ChartView in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am trying to get a reference to a dynamically created ChartView object. In the code you will see I dynamically create a Chart as the Delegate when I click the 'add chart' button.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtCharts 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1200
    height: 800
    title: "Charts"

    ListModel {
        id: modelId
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectId
        color: "pink"
        anchors.fill: parent

        GridView {
            id: mGridViewId
            anchors.fill: parent
            cellWidth: 300; cellHeight: 300
            model: modelId
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: mGridViewId.cellWidth;
                height: mGridViewId.cellHeight
                color: mColor

                ChartView {
                    width: parent.width;
                    height: parent.height

                    LineSeries {
                        name: "LineSeries"
                        XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0 }
                        XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 2.1 }
                        XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 3.3 } 
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Row {
            Button {
                text: "add chart"

                onClicked: {                    
                   modelId.append({'mColor': 'blue'})
                }
            }


            Button {
                text: "remove chart"

                onClicked: {
                    modelId.remove(0)
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            text: "add line series"

            onClicked: {
                var chart = modelId.get(0)
                chart.removeAllSeries();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I am able to get a reference to a specific item of the Model using :

```
var chart = modelId.get(0)
```

However it is not treated as a Rectangle nor a ChartView. So if I wanted to do something like add a LineSeries to one of the dynamically created Charts, or remove LineSeries like so:

```
onClicked: {
    var chart = modelId.get(0)
    chart.removeAllSeries();
}
```

I am unable to treat the object as a QML object. I get an error:

> qrc:/main.qml:80: TypeError: Property 'removeAllSeries' of object
>   QObject(0x7fd35d996b50) is not a function

I am not sure what I am doing this wrong or if I need to go about this in a totally different way, i.e. not using ListView-Model-Delegate and instead dynamically create a QML object and store references to them in an array.

Thanks for any help, I appreciate it.

--E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, posting the answer here for future nerdlings.

I needed to access the contentItem property of the GridView. I added this function to the GridView

```
function getDelegateInstanceAt(index) {
    return contentItem.children[index];
}
```

and to modify the specific delegate call the function passing the index

```
onClicked: {
    var chart = mGridViewId.getDelegateInstanceAt(2);
    chart.removeAllSeries();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

E, if I understand this right you whant to call the removeAllSeries() of a single ChartView qml Object you are creating.

but...

```
modelId.get(0)
```

is not the ChartView qml object, it is only the data element you added.
so the error you get is valid, because you try to access the properties of the ListModel

if you do this:

```
onClicked: {
    var chart = modelId.get(0)
    var color = chart.mColor
    console.log(color)
    // blue
}
```

you have to use the currentItem and or currentIndex of the GridView to find the right ChartView Object

```
onClicked: {
    //Gridview -> Rectangle -> ChartView -> method
    mGridViewId.currentItem.visibleChildren[0].removeAllSeries()
}
```

you may get rid of the extra Rectangle and do not have to deal with the visibleChildren.