# Dynamically Create ChartViews in QML with different lineSeries in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to find a means of creating dynamic chartviews using QML. The general idea is for a user to click an element on a ComboBox and click a button to either add a chartview to the screen or remove it.

Currently I'm able to display my charts statically in a RowLayout like so:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtCharts 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Item{ property int firstModel : 1 
      property int secondModel : 2
      property int maxVal : 8
      property int minVal: -8

        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 10
        
                ChartView{
                    id: firstModelChartView
                    animationOptions: ChartView.NoAnimation
                    theme: ChartView.ChartThemeLight
                    antialiasing: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
        
                    DateTimeAxis{
                        id:axisXValues
                        min:new Date(SensorManager.audioStream[firstModel].xMin)
                        max:new Date(SensorManager.audioStream[firstModel].xMax)
                        format: "hh:mm:ss:zzz"
                    }
        
                    ValueAxis {
                        id: axisYValues
                        min: gLinkMin
                        max: gLinkMax
                    }
        
                    LineSeries {
                        id:  innerChamberLineSeries
                        useOpenGL: true
                        name: "Inner Chamber"
                        axisX: axisXValues
                        axisY: axisYValues
        
                    }
        
                    VXYModelMapper {
                        id:  innerChamberLineSeriesModelMapper
                        model: SensorManager.audioStream[firstModel]
                        series: innerChamberLineSeries
                        firstRow: 1
                        xColumn: 0
                        yColumn: 1
                    }
                }
                /// SEcond Model ...... Etc You get the gist
        
            }

}
```

The model is a QAbstractModel Type from C++ and I'm able to display this in realtime. My problem is I've got 20 of these data streams and I don't want to show them all at once. so I want to give the user the ability to be able to add or remove multiple of these chartviews from the screen.

I'm trying to use a GridView and basically adapt this snippet from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123275/getting-reference-to-dynamically-created-chartview-in-qml)  but I'm not really getting far with it.

My Idea is to initially create a chartview and then attach a lineseries to that chartview, here's what I've got so far but I'm stumped on how to attach a specific lineseries model to a chartview and how you remove a specific chartview from the Gridview.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtCharts 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Item{ property int firstModel : 1 
      property int secondModel : 2
      property int maxVal : 8
      property int minVal: -8

    ListModel{
        id: chartsModel
        Component.onCompleted: {
            chartsModel.append({"name": qsTr("Inner Vinration Chamber"), value: firstModel })
            chartsModel.append({"name": qsTr("Extruder Vibration Y"), value: secondModel })
            ///////
    
    
        }
    }
    
    ListModel{
        id:chartViewModel
    
    }
        
    
    Row {
        id: chartControlsRow
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors{
            leftMargin: 10
            topMargin: 10
        }
        spacing:0
    
    
        CustomComboBox {
            id: chartSelector
            model: chartsModel
            textRole: "name"
            onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                var model = SensorManager.audioStream[chartsModel.get(currentIndex).value]
            }
        }
        
        CustomButton
        {
            id: addChartButton
            text: "Add Chart"
            onClicked: {
    
                modelId.append({'mColor': 'blue'})
                var chartViewModel = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.14; ListModel { }',
                                                        Qt.application, 'dynamicChartViewModel');
    
            }
        }
    
    
        CustomButton
        {
            id:removeChartButton
            text: "Remove Chart"
            onClicked: {
    
                console.log(chartSelector.currentIndex)
                chartViewModel.remove(chartSelector.currentIndex);
    
            }
        }
    
    
    }
    
    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.topMargin: 55
        color: "black"
    
        GridView {
            id: mGridViewId
            anchors.fill: parent
            cellWidth: 400; cellHeight: 400
            model: chartViewModel
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: mGridViewId.cellWidth;
                height: mGridViewId.cellHeight
                color: mColor
    
                ChartView {
                    id: mChartView
                    width: parent.width;
                    height: parent.height
    
                    DateTimeAxis{
                        id:axisXValues
                        format: "hh:mm:ss:zzz"
                    }
    
                    ValuesAxis{
                        id:axisYValues
                        min:gLinkMin
                        max:gLinkMax
                    }
    
                    LineSeries {
                        name: "Lineseries"
                        id: mLineSeries
                        useOpenGL: true
                        axisX: axisXValues
                        axisY: axisYValues
    
                    }
                    VXYModelMapper{
                        id: modelMapper
                        series: mLineSeries
                        firstRow: 1
                        xColumn: 0
                        yColumn: 1
                    }
    
                }
            }
    
            function getDelegateInstanceAt(index) {
                return contentItem.children[index];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I Achieve this? Any tips or pointers would be helpful